# When to calculate Cronbach's alpha for a paper?

Tags: cronbachs-alpha, reproducible-research

I am doing my undergraduate thesis, and I wonder if I need to do the Cronbach's alpha from my data set, or if I should use the Cronbach's alpha from the commercial questionnaire I will use for this paper. What is the standard way to approach this?

Comment: What do you mean data set? How is the commercial questionnaire not a data set? Explain, please. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice—at least in psychology—is to calculate and report a Cronbach's alpha for any scale that you create.

Say that you have a commercial questionnaire that is four items long: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, and Item 4. The standard approach is to simply average the participant's responses across those items. When we do that, we often report a Cronbach's alpha as a quick-and-dirty measure of reliability.

Here is an example from a paper I co-authored:

> We employed the same free speech items as in Studies 4 through 6
>   ($\alpha = $ .97), and used the symbolic racism scale ($\alpha = $.89;
>   Henry & Sears, 2002) to assess prejudice. Our measure of expressive
>   threat was slightly adapted from the autonomy subscale of the basic
>   psychological needs scale (Johnston & Finney, 2010): “I am free to
>   decide for myself how to live my life,” “I feel pressured to think
>   what others want me to think,” “I feel free to express my ideas and
>   opinions,” “I feel like I can pretty much be myself,” “I feel free to
>   be who I am,” “I can voice my opinion,” and “I feel controlled and
>   pressured to have certain beliefs” ($\alpha = $ .92). Items were
>   scored such that higher scores indicated more threat to expression.

They are easy to calculate in common statistical software you are likely using—like [R](https://rpubs.com/hauselin/reliabilityanalysis), [SPSS](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/cronbachs-alpha-using-spss-statistics.php), or [SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_examples09.htm). Make sure that if any of your items need to be reverse-scored you do so before calculating Cronbach's alpha.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  So even if I use a scale from a comrercial test, it is recommended to calxulate the alpha based on your own dataset. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, you should run it on your own dataset.